# Web scraping - SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document':

Tags: web-scraping

Can anyone help me? I'm doing web scraping. I want to click on the button. Here is my xpath code:

```
/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[18]/td[3]/width='20%'/input[3]
```

I got an error as follow. Can anyone explain why and what is the solution?

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': Type conversion failed while evaluating the expression.
```

Comment: What language? Application? Is there code generating this?

Comment: @QHarr I'm using robomotion tools to scrape this website. I'm copying the XPath code and pasting it into click element nodes. but it shows that error

Comment: @QHarr is there any error with my xpath code?

Comment: This looks wrong`width='20%'` though I don't know robomotion. That looks like part of a style attribute. Can you include the relevant table html?